# Is there a way to deploy GSuite app in our own server and run on GSuite Market place? So that every one can use that

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-apps, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I Wanted to create GSuite app and deploy in my own server instead of deploying in google cloud. Is there a way to do it? It would be great if i get some solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy G Suite apps/extensions to your own server - they must be published via Chrome Web Store and/or G Suite Marketplace.

What you can do when you publish your app, is to set it as *private* so that only users in your domain can see and install the app. See Step 4 on [Create and publish custom Chrome apps & extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en) page for more details. Obviously, the app must be published by a domain account - you don't get that option if you publish an app from your personal/Gmail account.

Comment: How do we save  db connection info, secret keys and some other confidential information if we are deploying in their store/marketplace?